# Looking for a XML minifier for node.js

Tags: xml, minify

I'm looking for a xml minifier for node.js like on this website.

http://www.webtoolkitonline.com/xml-minifier.html

Couldn't find anything.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out my NPM package [minify-xml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minify-xml). It allows you to minify XML easy & quick:

```
const minifyXML = require("minify-xml").minify;
 
const xml = `<Tag xmlns:used="used_ns" xmlns:unused="unused_ns">
    <!--
        With the default options all comments will be removed, whitespace in
        tags, like spaces between attributes, will be collapsed / removed and
        elements without any content will be collapsed to empty tag elements
    -->
    <AnotherTag attributeA   =   "..."   attributeB   =   "..."    ></AnotherTag>
 
    <!-- By default any unused namespaces will be removed from the tags: -->
    <used:NamespaceTag used:attribute = "...">
        any valid element content is left unaffected (strangely enough = " ... "
        and even > are valid characters in XML, only &lt; must always be encoded)
    </used:NamespaceTag>
 
    <![CDATA[<FakeTag attr = "content in CDATA tags is not minified"></FakeTag>]]>
</Tag>`;
 
console.log(minifyXML(xml));
```

Over the commonly available XML minification sites available, `minify-xml` also minifies attributes, as well as it removes unused XML namespaces.

Answer (score -5):

```
xml.replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

Didn't know that it'd be so easy. Solved it.

Comment: This will (a) Remove significant whitespace in CDATA blocks and (b) Not replace empty elements using start tag / end tag syntax with self-closing tag syntax.